# Another bigdata problem with group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

I have about 1 million rows and lots of columns in my dataframe. I need a `group_by` and `mutate` in order to clean my data. I impute missing values (negative numbers) by any other positive value for a specific person or group.

The following works fine:

```
library(tidyverse)
data = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), time=seq(1:3), x=rep(c(5:8), each=3))

data$x[3] <- -1 # negative numbers represent missings 
data$x[11] <- -1
data$x[12] <- -1

data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(fix = max(x)) # since it's a stable trait, I can impute any measurement for that id
```

But when I increase the size, it takes about 10 min or sometimes crashes (I have Intel Xeon E5 and 64 GB RAM):

```
bigdata = data.frame(id=rep(c(1:1000000), each=3), time=seq(1:3), x=rep(c(5:8), each=3))

bigdata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(fix = max(x))
```

How can I improve/speed up my code?

Comment: Have you tried this in an empty session? My system.time() gives 2.55 seconds. with 16GB RAM. What else do you have in your memory? You may want to remove very large un-needed objects from your memory first (see [Hadley about this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Comment: CPU and RAM is < 10 % It's challenging for me to provide better MWE. I have a tibble with lots of attributes and labels (original file was .dta from Stata). Might this cause a problem?

Comment: It definitely should not take that much time. I just ran the last code chunk on an Intel i5 16GB RAM (*way* below your specs) and it took about 1.86s (median over 10 repetitions). Your `bigdata` is not even big, it is a ~34 MB object. Are you sure there are not other possible bottlenecks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like people in the comments, I am struggling to reproduce the really slow runtime. If I run on 10 million my runtime is around 30 seconds so I will start from there:

```
library(dplyr)

bigdata = data.frame(id=rep(c(1:10000000), each=3), time=seq(1:3), x=rep(c(5:8), each=3))

system.time(bigdata %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(fix = max(x)))
```

user  system elapsed

34.83    2.66   37.48

Using data.table rather than dplyr gave a nice speedup. Theoretically, this might be more efficient for you in real life as data.table tries to do stuff without copying the dataset. Your dplyr code is probably copying the dataset every time you use %>% at least.

```
library(data.table)

dt = setDT(bigdata)
system.time(dt[,fit:=max(x),by=id])
df = setDF(dt)
```

user  system elapsed

12.29    1.71   12.12

I also use data from Stata imported using the foreign package. I haven't noticed issues with that.

Comment: Hi, I imported with `haven`. My tibble size is about 200MB. As I said, I don't know how to make a reproducable minimal example of my data. I will try `data.table`next, and one version when dropping all labels and attributes.

Comment: I am interested in hearing results as it may impact what I do in my own research. So far my experience is data.table is far faster but I am fairly new to it.

Comment: Preview: When dropping all attributes `lapply(df, function(x) { attributes(x) <- NULL; x })` my runtime improved a lot already. I need some more time to work through `data.table` and adjust my code. Havn't used it before, but it's designed for the job. So thank you :)